# How do I put a stopwatch on a video recording?

Tags: swift, timer, camera, overlay

I am a relatively new coder, and am creating an app for a class. The goal is to create an app that will record a video and have the current time of the video on the recording. The essential purpose is to record a cross country or track meet and be able to see the race time on the video.

We downloaded and edited this project:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos#toc-anchor-012

which records a video and makes it into a birthday card. I deleted the necessary code to remove animations and the background picture, just leaving an editable line of text. However, I cannot implement a timer to get this text to show the video time. Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: In the project, they use static views. You can create an animation with the current time and add it as an overlay.

It is not so easy for a new coder. Maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: How do I access the current time of the video? If I knew how to do that, I think I could figure out the overlay.

Comment: `AVPlayer` has a method `currentTime()` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390404-currenttime

Comment: Add `UILabel` with the current time to the screen is easy. But I don't think it is easy to add it to the recorded video.